# Xamarin Android Backgrounding Guidance

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, android-service, backgrounding

I thank everyone that helped me on my last question. I have been reading a lot about Android programming and backgrounding tasks and I have a few doubts about this diagram: 
http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/backgrounding/part_9_android_backgrounding_guidance/Images/image22.png

Which can be found on : http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/backgrounding/part_9_android_backgrounding_guidance/

1. According to the diagram if I want to do cleanup tasks on an Activity I should de them on the "OnPause" event but make it fast: if it thakes them a long time it will freeze the layout? Is there a chance my app will be forcefully finished before the cleanup can finish?
2. Why I don't want to run a task on an Activity when it is backgrounded? At first I thought that it was because it would stop working but I see that if I don't stop my code it will keep running but it is not the case. Why should I use a service if a I can keep doing tasks even if my Activity is backgrounded?
3. In the case of the remote services branch of the diagram: the Messenger serves what purpose other than send Messages to the Service? Can I receive information from the service using Messages or I need another way to get answers from the service?
4. Another about remote: I read the AIDL that is mentioned is not supported by Xamarin at the moment, how can I implement it?
5. In the case of starting a long-running task: I should use a service so to ensure that my task will be done?
6. How can I start a Service at device boot-up?
7. If Android forces a sticky service to restart: all objects bound to it are still bound? Or I have to bound them again?
8. Can I send objects to a Service?

I know, a lot of questions. Most of them were asked by my boss so I want to give him the best answers.

Thanks in advance!!!

[Edit: 20140320]
Some answers, if I am wrong please tell me.

1. Android can Destroy backgrounded activities if it sees fit.
2. Same as 1
3. Do any of you have a nice example using Server Messengers in Xamarin?
4. Guess that it is same as 1 and 2. A backgrounded Activity will be destroyed if Android sees fit. A Service could survive more than the calling activity.

Comment: Does your boss have an account on SO?

Comment: Don't know... anyway I am learning here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Edit: 20140320] Some answers, if I am wrong please tell me.

Android can Destroy backgrounded activities if it sees fit.

Same as 1

Do any of you have a nice example using Server Messengers in Xamarin?

Guess that it is same as 1 and 2. A backgrounded Activity will be destroyed if Android sees fit. A Service could survive more than the calling activity.